# OrientDB Register Custom Function for Aggregation Java

Tags: orientdb

As written at the bottom in this page http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Functions.html , we can build our custom function in OrientDB. However, this example just shows a custom function to perform an inline operation. Is there any way to write an OrientDB function that performs an aggregation operation? Something like sum(fieldName) . So the question is more towards how we can access the 'current' record value for that field inside our custom function so that we can perform an aggregation operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at this: [OSQLFunctionSum](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/sql/functions/math/OSQLFunctionSum.java)

The code is quite simple, but the important concepts are following:

1. `aggregateResults()` has to return `true` to let OrientDB know that it's an aggregate function
2. OrientDB will aggregate records for you and will return a an instance of your function for every aggregation.
3. you have to keep aggregate data in your function instance (see `private Number             sum;` in the example)
4. `execute()` method is invoked for every record, during query
5. `getResult()` must return the aggregate result